# ADO.NET EntityObject Generator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0

I've just installed VS.NET 2010 and discovered that ADO.NET EntityObject generator exists as a new item.

Do u have more docs on it? i surfed on the net, but i found only two urls' speaking about that (even if i can't understoo what actually it is)

**Update**:

[What’s New in Entity Framework 4? Part 1: API Changes](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0909081)

[ADO.NET EntityObject Generator: how to get the EntityType’s EntitySet and how to get EntitySet’s EntityTypes](http://msmvps.com/blogs/matthieu/archive/2009/09/02/ado-net-entityobject-generator-how-to-get-the-entitytype-s-entityset-and-how-to-get-entityset-s-entitytypes.aspx)

[EF4: What is and is not supported](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ef4-what-is-and-is-not-supported/)

[Customizing EDM Code Gen in EF4](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/customizing-edm-code-gen-in-ef4/)

Comment: Could you edit your post and include the URLs so the rest of SO can read and interpret these articles? Thanks.

Comment: hi jason, i just updated my question, hope u can help me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Customizing Entity Classes in VS 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/01/22/customizing-entity-classes-with-t4.aspx).